# Definition in category theory.

Tags: category-theory, definition

In category theory, which is the definition of "contravariant involution"? and this is different of contravariant functor?

Comment: Probably a contravariant functor whose square is the identity.

Comment: @ziggurism To be explicit though, given a functor $F:\mathcal{C}^{op}\to\mathcal{C}$, it doesn't compose with itself, so you'd need something like $F\circ F^{op} = Id_\mathcal{C}$.

Comment: @DerekElkins agreed, technically that would be necessary.

Comment: @DerekElkins So, is that  the definition?

Comment: @Gödel It's what I'd guess (or perhaps a weakening of it). Google only gives me 327 hits for "contravariant involution" (as compared to 44,400 for "contravariant functor" to give scale). You'll have to consult whatever you read that used the term for a definition (if it's an instructor, you can just ask them). If it doesn't provide a definition, you'll just need to infer what is meant from context.

Comment: @DerekElkins this notion appear in a paper but only as a comment, there is not clear context because the paper is not about category theory.

Comment: @Gödel Can you link to the paper?

Comment: @NoahSchweber this is the paper http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~ablass/hbk.pdf, when the author defines morphis between relations (page 17).

Comment: The meaning in ziggurism's comment is what I meant.

Comment: @AndreasBlass thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me first recall the context of [the paper in which the phrase occurs](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~ablass/hbk.pdf).

- A *relation* is understood to be a triple $(A_-, A_+, A)$ where $A_-, A_+$ are arbitrary sets (of *challenges* and *responses*, respectively) and $A\subseteq A_-\times A_+$.
- A *morphism* $\varphi$ from ${\bf A}$ to ${\bf B}$ is a pair of functions $$\varphi_-: B_-\rightarrow A_-,\quad \varphi_+: A_+\rightarrow B_+$$ such that for all $y\in B_-$ and $x\in A_+$ we have $\varphi_-(y)Ax\implies yB\varphi_+(x)$. This gives the class of relations the structure of a category, call it $\mathcal{R}$.

Now, the *dual* of a relation ${\bf A}=(A_-, A_+, A)$ is the relation ${\bf A^\perp}=(A_-, A_+, \neg \check{A})$, where $\neg$ denotes complementation and $\check\cdot$ denotes the converse; we have $(x, y)\in\neg\check{A}$ iff $(y, x)\not\in A$. A good motivating example is "dominates" versus "escapes" in the context where $A_-=A_+=\mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$.

There is also a natural notion of the dual $\varphi^\perp$ of a morphism $\varphi$: namely, swap $\varphi_-$ and $\varphi_+$. Blass doesn't actually use the term "dual" here, but the superscript $^\perp$ is used in both cases. At this point it's easy to check that the duality map - acting as ${\bf A}\mapsto{\bf A^\perp}$ on objects and $\varphi\mapsto \varphi^\perp$ on morphisms - is a contravariant functor from a category to itself whose square is the identity. So it seems fairly clear that this is what "contravariant involution" means.

If you are still not satisfied, you can always email the author of the paper (Andreas Blass).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is so useful to me.